# Image manipulation in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick

I am uploading images in Meteor with `CollectionFS`.

It works but I am also interested in creating thumbnails to the images.

I have followed https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#image-manipulation but I cannot get `GraphicsMagick` to work.

If I just use

```
var createThumb = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
  readStream.pipe(writeStream);
};
```

the code works but the image is not resized (the thumbnail equals orginal image as it should). But when I call

```
gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('10', '10').stream().pipe(writeStream);
```

to resize the image to a 10x10 thumbnail, the code works but the thumbnail is not created correctly. The thumbnail is created but its size is 0kb. I suspect `GraphicsMagick` is not installed correctly. I have downloaded and installed the Windows binary and added `cfs:graphicsmagick` to `packages`.

Are there any alternatives for `GraphicsMagick`? I would rather avoid using any third parties since `GraphicsMagick` is not installed on Meteor's free development servers and I want the app to be easily portable. Maybe image manipulation is such a advanced task that it cannot be done directly in javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do these steps?

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#image-manipulation

> A common use for transformWrite is to manipulate images before saving
>   them. To get this set up:
>
> - Install GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick on your development machine and
>     on any server that will host your app. (The free Meteor deployment
>     servers do not have either of these, so you can't deploy to there.)
>     These are normal operating system applications, so you have to install
>     them using the correct method for your OS. For example, on Mac OSX you
>     can use `brew install graphicsmagick` assuming you have Homebrew
>     installed.
> - Add the `cfs:graphicsmagick` Meteor package to your app:
>     `meteor add cfs:graphicsmagick`

Comment: Yes I did. I have both tried installing in 32bit and 64bit